# AWS Aurora Serverless v2 Access

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-aurora

I am trying to read/write to my Aurora Serverless v2 instance in AWS from a website hosted with AWS Amplify.

Just to clarify, is the only option for acccessing a Aurora MySQL Serverless v2 instance via a Lambda function?

I understand that there isn't a Data API for v2 and therefore, AWS AppSync cannot be used.

This doc from AWS talks about accessing via Lambda. I'm concerned about the capabilities of the function. Could a lambda func handle numerous calls?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-rds-tutorial.html

Comment: You can connect to an Aurora cluster the same way as any normal database: [Connecting to an Amazon Aurora DB cluster - Amazon Aurora](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Connecting.html) Access is _not_ limited to using an AWS Lambda function.

Comment: but programatically, the only option is Lambda? importing pymysql pythonically @JohnRotenstein

Comment: You can use a MySQL driver and connect via the cluster endpoint, same as any other DB.

Comment: Your code can run anywhere on the Internet. It does not need to run in an AWS Lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda is a good general-purpose way to pass data into and out of the database. A lot of people hook up calls to Lambda to do change data capture (CDC), where there's a call for every modification (such as DML statements) to the database. If you are worried about the number of calls, add an RDS Proxy to the cluster. That way you'll have a connection pool and many short-lived connections won't stress the CPU or memory of the database.